# Как заполнить одномерный массив несколькими словами?

Tags: c, массивы

Нужно заполнить массив несколькими словами. 
Например, в него должно входить предложение "It is a trap".
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: char lazyStudent[] = "It is a trap. Foo Bar Upyatchka"

Comment: char *akbar_says[] = { "It", "is", "a", "trap" };

Answer (score -3):

Нужно использовать функцию gets()
Функция gets принимает в качестве своего аргумента массив символов, в который она и записывает считываемую из стандартного потока ввода строку.

Например:

```
    char inp[255];
    gets(inp);   // введем предложение "It is a trap"
    printf("%s", inp); // программа выведет "It is a trap"
```

Comment: А можно использовать любую из бесконечного числа функций, да.

Comment: У gets проблемы с безопасностью, лучше использовать fgets ().